# google gcm raw_data (payload encryption) , push event not received

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, push, payload, web-push, raw-data

I need some help because i never receive push event in my serviceworker after payload encryption.

1. First case without payload encrypted

In this case, I receive push event in service worker:

- Request is :

```
curl -s --header "Authorization: key=MY_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "TTL:86400" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"elmll0-ynBY:APA91bFe7xBGti92H4yrWo2bJT6aMY3IKo3j54yRGtS0NNQYpkqmI5f14EKSPz6_GCEs2PaX6zCD3Lvk-2JRABQVZ3u350bsy0uisxRL0EoZnVHsqVMo7YNojkvQX7o49a61pCmZEfSi\"],\"delay_while_idle\":false,\"collapse_key\":\"hipush-notification\",\"time_to_live\":86400}"
```

- Google response is :

```
{"multicast_id":5772871775830750210,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1465913797471899%f4d428f3bf364ddd"}]}
```

2. Second test, with encrypted raw_data

I never receive push event:
- Request is :

```
curl -s --header "Authorization: key=MY_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "TTL:86400" --header "Encryption: salt=KYw1fpU-Dg4w1qFcrPY3rQ" --header "Crypto-Key: dh=BOwb4OiwboYRrbhhXh056xFZ8pk8kfQR27Gmu3EdYPG9DkLoKRqA_d4Z_TbT2VYMfHVkGS-dY45rZ8tAimqSWrk" --header "Content-Encoding:aesgcm" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send --header "Content-Length: 363" -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"elmll0-ynBY:APA91bFe7xBGti92H4yrWo2bJT6aMY3IKo3j54yRGtS0NNQYpkqmI5f14EKSPz6_GCEs2PaX6zCD3Lvk-2JRABQVZ3u350bsy0uisxRL0EoZnVHsqVMo7YNojkvQX7o49a61pCmZEfSi\"],\"delay_while_idle\":false,\"collapse_key\":\"hipush-notification\",\"time_to_live\":86400,\"raw_data\":\"rXJHqmhxmTde+297wtb3Tpj5Lq5C8cd2eYW5qTBoC3huGVTOPog6+I2Y6wQEYqP1QIAvUA0NFtYC7Zr\/iCR1sGcu\"}"
```

- Google response is :

```
 {"multicast_id":7840093467258640262,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1465913901129815%f4d428f3bf364ddd"}]}
```

I got same response with success. My chrome is in version 51.

Can someone explain me where is my error ?

Best regards,

Mehdi

Answer (score 2):

Which language are you using? You could use one of the libraries here https://github.com/web-push-libs (Node.js, PHP, Python, Java currently supported), which have already fixed the problem for you.